# Subfield Test for a Field of Characteristic 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am trying to prove that $K = \{x \in F | x^p = x \}$ for a field $F$ of prime characteristic $p$ is a subfield of $F$.  The first part of the subfield test (proving that, given $a, b \in K$, $(a - b) \in K$) seems to work for primes other than 2 because, for $b \in K$, $b^p = b \implies (-b)^p = -b$ and $(x + y)^p = x^p + y^p$.  How does this work for $p = 2$?  I get to this point:
$$
(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + (-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 = a + b,
$$
but I need it to be eventually equal to $a - b$.

Comment: Try changing the title. It does _not_ address the question

Comment: Is that better?  I am having a hard time narrowing down a title because I am so new to fields in general.

Comment: Just prove that $x \mapsto x^p$ is a ring homomorphism and you’re pretty much done. Don’t worry about any special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: I just noticed that your question addresses something more basic. In $\mathrm{char} K = 2$, you have that $b+b = b(1+1) = b\cdot 0 = 0$. So $b = -b$ and then $a+b = a-b$ and the subfield test works.

You have all the nice properties (commutativity, associativity) from the operations. Prove, then, that the neutral elements belong to the set, that it is multiplicatively closed (and inverses - that will agree with the base field - belong to the set) and that the set is additively closed.

The first two are easy, since $0^p = 0,\ 1^p = 1$ and $(xy)^p =  x^p y^p =  xy,\ (x^{-1})^p = (x^p)^{-1} = x^{-1}$. The additive part is a bit tricky, but remember that fields are commutative and the binomial theorem holds. So $$(x+y)^p = \sum \binom{p}{k} x^{p-k}y^k.$$

What you have to prove is that $\binom{p}{k} =  \frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$ is a  multiple of $p$ whenever  $k \not \in \{0,p\}$. Now look what the denominator looks like when that happens and remember that $p$ is  prime.

Comment: Thank you so much!